# Atom - Julia: Completion of Unicode character (such as \pi) with `Tab` suddenly stops working

Tags: unicode, julia, atom-editor

I'm using `Julia 1.0.3` on a `macOS 10.14` and `Atom 1.33.1`, `latex completions 0.3.6`

I want to use unicode character such as `ν` or `π`

However after functioning properly for a few times, the completion with `Tab` stops functioning (e.g.: when I type `\pi` + `Tab` it doesn't work although it worked for the previous `ν` and it doesn't work either when I want to type a new `ν`).

Any idea?

[image]

Comment: Are you using https://github.com/JunoLab/atom-latex-completions?

Comment: Thank you for your comment @hash_purple. Yes, I use atom-latex-completions. After your comment, I uninstalled and re-installed it (currently version 0.3.6), but the problem persists: I launch the script, works a few times, and then doesn't work anymore

Comment: What version of Atom are you running in julia package?  (v1.0) pkg> status
    Status `~/.julia/environments/v1.0/Project.toml`
  [c52e3926] Atom v0.7.11

Comment: thanks @Steven Siew. I acually ask the question on another forum and got the answer: I had to run `Pkg.update()` and it worked.